# Regex to match everything except the given words (which may include hyphens/dashes)

Tags: regex

I would like to match everything except the given word(s), so given this list:

```
wordOne
wordTwo/xy/z
word-three
word-four/lots/of/stuff
```

I could use this regexp to match everything except wordOne:

```
(?!wordOne)\b.+
  ==>
    wordTwo/xy/z
    word-three
    word-four/lots/of/stuff
```

However if I want to match everything **except one of the words containing a hyphen/dash**, the same regexp does not work, because the hyphen is not a part of the word boundary - which is [a-zA-Z0-9_]

E.g

```
some-regexp(word-four)
  ==>
    wordOne
    wordTwo/xy/z
    word-three
```

And

```
some-regexp(word-four and word-three)
  ==>
    wordOne
    wordTwo/xy/z
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I can see you define one word per line in your examples. In this case this regex should work for you:

```
^(?:(?!word-four|word-three).)*$
```

it skips the words which contain `word-four` or `word-three`.

As per your examples:

```
^(?:(?!wordOne).)*$
  ==>
    wordTwo/xy/z
    word-three
    word-four/lots/of/stuff 

^(?:(?!word-four).)*$
  ==>
    wordTwo/xy/z
    word-three
    word-four/lots/of/stuff 

^(?:(?!word-four|word-three).)*$
  ==>
    wordOne
    wordTwo/xy/z
```

See it on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/bapb1OLyzG).